# 'RandStream' is not defined in MATLAB 7.6.0.324?

Tags: matlab, random, seed

I am trying to use `RandStream` in MATLAB 7.6.0.324 as below:

```
randst = RandStream('mrg32k3a', 'Seed', 0);
```

Apparently, `RandStream` is not defined on MATLAB 7.6.0.324 and I can not find a documentation about it.

How can I set random seed in this version of Matlab then for `rand` and `randperm`.

Comment: I am using matlab version 7.11.0.584 (R2010b). I ran the code you posted with no problem. Can you give the specific error??

Comment: "Undefined function or method 'RandStream' for input arguments of type 'char'."

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you got code from someone who uses a newer version of MATLAB. The `RandStream` function was introduced in later versions of MATLAB (I don't remember which) and as you found out, does not exist in v7.6.0.324. In older versions, you simply set the seed inside `rand` like so:

```
rand('seed',0);
x=rand(1,5)

x =

0.2190    0.0470    0.6789    0.6793    0.9347
```

`randperm` on the other hand, calls `rand` inside it. So setting the seed for `rand` before calling `randperm` will give you the same output each time.

```
rand('seed',0);
y=randperm(5)

y =

     2     1     3     4     5
```

---

#### NOTE:

This syntax is not currently recommended (and support may be discontinued in future releases). From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/bsn94u0-1.html):

> These rand and randn syntaxes are no
> longer recommended for the following
> reasons:
>
> - The terms 'seed' and 'state' are misleading names for the generators.
> - All of the former generators except 'twister' are flawed.
> - They unnecessarily use different generators for rand and randn.

Comment: @farzaneh: `randperm` is just a wrapper function that calls `rand` inside it. So if you do `rand('seed',0); randperm(10)`, you'll get the same permutation each time.

Answer (score 0):

you're obviously using an old version where the function hasn't been defined yet

try [qrandstream](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2008a/toolbox/stats/index.html?/help/releases/R2008a/toolbox/stats/bqttfc1.html&http://www.mathworks.com/cgi-bin/texis/webinator/search/.html?docr2008a=docr2008a&query=rand%20stream&pr=docr2008a&prox=page&rorder=750&rprox=750&rdfreq=500&rwfreq=500&rlead=250&rdepth=0&sufs=0&order=r&cq=&is_summary_on=1&ResultCount=10)